# Existence of operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T$  is hermitian operator  from space $V$ to $V$, show that $S$ operator  that uphold $S^3=T$ and $S=S^*$ exist and unique.

From what I'm understanding,  $S$ operator must be unitary and hermitian operator,  but I don't know how to prove that his existence and unique.

Thanks  for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $S$ is not unitary.  For existence, use the continuous functional calculus or the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: I still don't understand how to do it. Cab you show me the solution with the spectral theorem?

Comment: It depends on which version of the spectral theorem you use.  If you use the multiplication operator version, where $T$ is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by $f$, then $S$ corresponds (with the same unitary operator) to multiplication by $f^{1/3}$.  If you use the projection-valued measure version where $T = \int \lambda \; dE_\lambda$, then $S = \int \lambda^{1/3}\; dE_\lambda$.

Comment: I appreciate your help,  but I think this solution is not for my level.   This is my first course in linear algebra  and we never used Integrals  or things that close to that.

Comment: OK, I thought this was on a Hilbert space.  Just do a diagonalization by unitary operator: $T = U D U^*$, and $S = U D^{1/3} U^*$ where $D^{1/3}$ has the cube roots of the diagonal elements of the diagonal matrix $D$.